# Add character after each word in a string (multibyte-safe)

Tags: php, implode, multibyte

How can I implode character after each word?

I have tried the following:

```
$query = implode("* ", preg_split("/[\s]+/", $query));
```

but it always ignores one word. for example: `test test` will give me `test* test`, `test` will give me `test`, test test test test will give me `test* test* test* test`

Also tried `$query = implode("*", str_split($query));` but it gives me gibberish if query is in Cyrillic characters.

Comment: Add `*` to the end of `$query`

Comment: Is there any problem appending "`*`" manually? like `implode("* ", preg_split("/[\s]+/", $query))."*";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`implode` will join strings together and insert a "glue string" in between each item.

If you want to change each and every string, you can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) instead.

```
implode(array_map(function($item) { return $item . '* '; }, $array));
```

And I hope you are not doing funky stuff with a database query (considering your variable name). If you want to use variable db queries, use parametrized queries instead.

Another "hack" is to implode your array and then insert the missing string at the end of the resulting string:

```
implode('* ', $array) . '* ';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php

$str = 'test test test test test';  
$str = implode("* ", explode(" ", $str))."* ";

echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try other answers or you can also use `preg_replace`. But not recommended. Avoid using `regex` when there is some clean alternatives available.

```
<?php
  $query  = preg_replace( "/[\s]+/", "* ", $query )."*";
  echo $query;
?>
```

Using `array_map`

```
<?php
  $query  = explode( " ", "test test test test test" );
  $query  = array_map( function( $val ) {
    return trim( $val )."* ";
  }, $query );
  $query  = implode( "", $query );
  echo $query;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most directly, use `preg_replace()` to insert an `*` after each word.

`\w+` will match one or more alphanumeric or underscore characters.
`\K` tells the function to restart the full string match -- so that no characters are removed during replacement.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ggO9I))

```
$string = 'test test test test';

echo preg_replace("/\w+\K/", '*', $string);
// output: test* test* test* test*
```

For multibyte characters such as cyrillic, add the `u` pattern modifier.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Md71M))

```
$string = 'слово слово слово слово';

echo preg_replace("/\w+\K/u", '*', $string);
// output: слово* слово* слово* слово*
```